# Change from amazon jdk to openjdk

Tags: java

I have an application that has been built using the amazon jdk (1.8.0_181 version). Which could be the problems of changing the jdk to openjdk but to a similar version? I don't know if the only difference between jdk's distributions is the support.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the version is similar you can expect the API to be the same. From [Which Java SDK Should You Use?](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/01/16/which-java-sdk)

> Amazon is the new vendor on the block that’s offering builds of OpenJDK at aws.amazon.com/corretto. Amazon Corretto 8 (based on Java 8) is in preview; there is no Java 11 build available. Corretto 11 is scheduled to be released in Q2 2019. GA for Corretto 8 is Q1. Corretto is unique in that it has no-cost long-term support from Amazon. Its builds have passed the TCK. Java 8 support is currently slated to run through June 2023.

> Oracle builds and publishes OpenJDK builds at jdk.java.net. Binaries are only published for the first six months after a major release. The branded, commercial version (that can’t be used in production without paying Oracle) is available at oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.